# Bootstrap Validate on dynamic element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have an input element(EngVDCategory) with an span addbutton(+) attached to it. On click of span (+), an additional element is being appended to element(EngVDCategory2).  This way the user can add more inputs dynamically. This is being done with append.
The problem here is bootstrap validates only the elements those are defined already and not the input elements which are added dynamically. How to validate the newly appended elements?

**My HTML**

```
<div class="VDGroup">
          <div class="VDGroupPlaceHolder">
             <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Engineering and Vendor data</label>
                <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
                   <div class="input-group">
                      <input type="text" id="EngVDCategory" name="EngVDCategory" placeholder="Engineering and Vendor data" class="form-control">
                      <span class="input-group-addon cursor" id='addButton'><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus "  ></i></span>
                      <span class="input-group-addon cursor" id='removeButton'><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" ></i></span>
                   </div>
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
```

**JS Validate**

```
 $('#filterForm').bootstrapValidator({

        fields: {
            EngVDCategory: {
                validators: {

                        stringLength: {
                            min: 10,
                            max: 100,
                            message: 'The name must be more than 10 and less than 100 characters long'
                        }

                }
            },
                        EngVDCategory2: {
                validators: {

                        stringLength: {
                            min: 10,
                            max: 100,
                            message: 'The name must be more than 10 and less than 100 characters long'
                        }

                }
            }
        }
 
    });
```

**JS to append input elements dynamically**

```
$("#addButton").click(function () {
                  if( ($('.VDGroup .VDGroupPlaceHolder').length+1) > 5) {
                      alert("Only maximum of 5 Categories are allowed");
                      return false;
                  }
                  var id = ($('.VDGroup .VDGroupPlaceHolder').length + 1).toString();
                  $('.VDGroup').append('<div class="VDGroupPlaceHolder"><div class="form-group"><label class="col-md-4 control-label">Engineering and Vendor data</label><div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer"><input type="text" id="EngVDCategory' + id + '" name="EngVDCategory' + id + '" placeholder="Engineering and Vendor data ' + id + '" class="form-control" ></div></div></div>');
                 // validator.addField($(this));
              });
```

**Screenshot on validation being done only on initially defined element and not on appended element**

[image]

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355920/jquery-validation-on-input-append-twitter-bootstrap

Comment: nope, as that was related more to the controls placement rather than validation itself.